# Stackoverflow in setcontext()

Tags: c, multithreading, process, stack-overflow

Below is code I seen on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setcontext). Does this results in stack overflow?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ucontext.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]){
    ucontext_t context;

    getcontext(&context);
    puts("Hello world");
    sleep(1);
    setcontext(&context);
    return 0;
}
```

Why:  When code reaches to `setcontext()`, it push new frame on stack. As `setcontext()` does not return, it's pushed frame will remain on stack. And as program is in infinite loop, it goes on pushing new frames on stack leading to stack overflow.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: you can read up the getcontext/setcontext description at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/getcontext.html. It mentioned that setcontext only restore the context, it does not mention anything about pushing new stack frame.

Comment: @MartinJames It's an infinite loop. It will go on printing "Hello World"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setcontext` will return the stack to the state it was at `getcontext`.

When you call `setcontext`, a new stack frame is pushed to the stack. `setcontext` will then revert the stack to the way it looked at `getcontext`, effectively removing the frame.

So the program does indeed create an infinite loop, but it will not result in stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

gdb says otherwise:

```
(gdb) list
1   #include <stdio.h>
2   #include <ucontext.h>
3   #include <unistd.h>
4   
5   int main(int argc, const char *argv[]){
6       ucontext_t context;
7   
8       getcontext(&context);
9       puts("Hello world");
10      //sleep(1);
(gdb) break 9
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4005bb: file test.c, line 9.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/dtarcatu/workspace/ctest/test 

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe008) at test.c:9
9       puts("Hello world");
(gdb) print $rbp
$1 = (void *) 0x7fffffffdf20
(gdb) print $rsp
$2 = (void *) 0x7fffffffdb60
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Hello world

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe008) at test.c:9
9       puts("Hello world");
(gdb) print $rbp
$3 = (void *) 0x7fffffffdf20
(gdb) print $rsp
$4 = (void *) 0x7fffffffdb60
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Hello world

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe008) at test.c:9
9       puts("Hello world");
(gdb) print $rbp
$5 = (void *) 0x7fffffffdf20
(gdb) print $rsp
$6 = (void *) 0x7fffffffdb60
```

I'm not familiar with these context handling functions but it seems `setcontext` does not push new frames to the stack but rather restores the stack exactly the way it was. So you'll just end up in an infinite loop - no stack overflow ...

Comment: Thanks @dragosht. When any function is called, stack frame is pushed. If you try like `(gdb)break setcontext (gdb)info registers ebp esp`, you will get different esp from other breakpoints. Internally setcontext overwrite it's own stack frame by setting esp which was previously saved at getcontext() and that's why you get same esp every time. So there is infinite loop but no stack overflow.